# C# Collection for "most recently used"

Tags: c#

I am trying to decide what is the best solution for "most recently used" collection. Intuitively, it's neither LIFO nor FIFO. as far as "removing" items it's FIFO; but as far as "retrieving" it's LIFO. So, both queue and stack have some limitations.

Or I am overthinking this whole thing and should just stick to Arrays or Lists?

Comment: A `Stack<T>` is quite useful for UI as the length isn't too long so you can always use `stack = new Stack<T>(stack.Skip(1));` to pop from the front.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest a LinkedList collection. The LinkedList holds references to the first and last node in the list (effectively letting you travel in LRU/MRU order). It also has `AddFirst` and `Remove` methods so you can remove the value and move it when a value from the list is used. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! Haven't thought about it :)

Comment: [Here](https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=625) an implementation